# Settings wont open after going to Devices panel: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: gnome, 19.10, gnome-control-center

I just opened the Settings program on Ubuntu 19.10 (`gnome-control-center`) and went to the "Devices" panel. Instead of showing me the panel, the control center showed a blank white panel and then closed.

Now if I try to open the control center it opens and closes right away. Starting it from the console I see the following error

```
$ gnome-control-center 

(gnome-control-center:22753): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 15:00:26.434: no sunset data, using 16.00

(gnome-control-center:22753): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 15:00:26.435: no sunrise data, using 8.00
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can reset the control center to a good state with

```
dconf reset -f /org/gnome/control-center/
```